# iOS video pauses on un-mute

Tags: ios, cordova, html5-video, wkwebview, http-live-streaming

I'm loading a video in a WKWebView.

```
var video_el = document.createElement('video');
video_el.controls = true;
video_el.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline');// Fix fullscreen problem on IOS 8 and 9
video_el.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');// Fix fullscreen problem on IOS 10
video_el.src = ' https://video.com/playlist.m3u8';
video_el.style.width = "720px";
video_el.style.height = "480px";
video_el.style.position = 'absolute';
video_el.style.top = 0;
video_el.style.left = 0;
video_el.autoplay = true;        
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(video_el);
```

When I try to play the video nothing happens.

Then I mute the video:

```
video_el.muted = true
```

Video plays with mute.

Then I turn mute off and video automatically pauses:

```
video_el.muted = false
```

Trying to press play on controls, video, or programmatically results in a stutter from play back to pause.

```
video_el.play();
```

Here's also my WKWebView configuration:

```
- (WKWebViewConfiguration*) createConfigurationFromSettings:(NSDictionary*)settings
    {
    WKWebViewConfiguration* configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    configuration.processPool = [[CDVWKProcessPoolFactory sharedFactory] sharedProcessPool];
    if (settings == nil) {
        return configuration;
    }

    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone;
    configuration.suppressesIncrementalRendering = [settings cordovaBoolSettingForKey:@"SuppressesIncrementalRendering" defaultValue:NO];
    configuration.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = [settings cordovaBoolSettingForKey:@"MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay" defaultValue:YES];
    return configuration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the culprit has something to do with background mode.
I was using a background plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) and when it was enabled it would make videos pause after play:

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

Toggling this off when playing a video solved the problem.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disable();
```